# Redefine a symbol with \newunicodechar and pdflatex

Tags: newunicodechar

EDIT: @egreg. but how do I change the single quote `›`, for instance, I want this  in the whole document,

```
\newunicodechar{›}{\unskip\,›}
```

**except** where, in a precise  environment, it becomes

```
\newenvironment{Screenplay}
{\parskip=0em
\relax\newunicodechar{›}{\ignorespaces›~}
}
{\par}
```

so that when I write in the screenplay environment, each `›` becomes `\ignorespaces›~`.

## Sometimes I can use xelatex or lualatex, but not always. This time, It must work with pdflatex and xelatex.

I use pdflatex and I want to redefine, without loading some package for languages,  the symbol for paragraph (but also for the **single** quote `‹` as found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#French )

What I use fails:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}



\usepackage[verbose]{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{§}{\unskip\,§K}

\begin{document}


§


\end{document}
```

Comment: assuming you have the `fontenc` package loaded with an enoding other than OT1: `\newunicodechar{›}{\ifhmode\unskip\,\fi\guilsinglright}`

Answer (score 3):

You can't redefine a Unicode character in terms of itself, but you can always use its LICR; for `§` it is `S`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[verbose]{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{§}{\ifhmode\unskip\,\fi\S K}

\begin{document}

a § b

\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem is that `§` in pdflatex is much like a macro and we're redefining it, so you go into an infinite loop if you want to define it in terms of itself.

I added a test for horizontal mode, because issuing `\unskip\,` in vertical mode would give unexpected results.

---

The situation is different with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, where an object such as `§` is actually a character, not a shorthand for a macro. So with those engines your attempt would work.

Comment: Brainfart on my part.  Thanks for providing remedy.